# Convert PDF Binary data to PDF File using python

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, bytesio

I am hitting an API, from where I am receiving pdf file,
When I try to convert the binary data received from API to PDF File using below.

`resp = request.get(url=url)`
`with open('test.pdf', 'wb') as pdffile:`
 `pdffile.write(resp.content)`

However with this approach file is being save but data is incomplete.
Also I am doing this on web application, I don't want to save the file on server, just wanna keep it in buffer memory and store it in a binary field.

Please let me know if anymore information is needed,
I am using Odoo ERP system.

Thank you in Advance.

Binary Data Format starts with b'%PDF-1.6

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use a BytesIO object

```
import io
with io.BytesIO(resp.content) as pdf_file:
#Do something with pdf_file
```